# Node and Axios - How to make sequentials requests

Tags: mysql, node.js, axios

I need to make 2 requests to my API to insert data in 2 different table:

Workflow:

**request to get the last id + 1 => create the array I need (last_id, values) => two INSERT in MySql, 1st with varius data, 2nd with the array I created.**

```
router.post("/addentry", function (req, res) {
    
let sql = "SELECT MAX(id) + 1 AS last_id FROM entries;"; // I get the id

  let query = connection
    .query(sql, (err, results) => {
      if (err) throw err;
     
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        
    // put the id in a variable

    var last_id = results[0].last_id;

    var categoriesMap = req.body.categories;

    var valCat = Object.values(categoriesMap);

    // I create the array with other data
 
    var catArray = valCat.map((item) => {
        return [last_id, item];
      });

    })
    .then((catArray) => {
    let sql = `BEGIN; INSERT INTO entries (title,kindof) VALUES("${[
        req.body.title,
      ]}","${req.body.kindof}");
     INSERT INTO categories_main (entry_id, cat_id) VALUES  ? ;
     COMMIT;`;

     let query = connection.query(sql, [catArray], (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(results);
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.send("Entry added to DB");
      });
    });
```

The first part works perfectly but with the second I get

```
TypeError: connection.query(...).then is not a function
```

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Your second error is due to the fact that you are still in your connection to the database, but you are trying to change your header. It was already set initially (after you first check for errors).

Comment: true. thanks. I thought it needed it for every query. I edited it to make it simpler.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help with your other problem: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52185624/11023871)

Comment: I think my case is different I don't have any connection problem. I need to send a second request once the one is over

Comment: Are you using `node-mysql` or `node-mysql2`

Comment: the one. I didn't even know about a second. I just installed. let me try to understand the promises with that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218346/discussion-between-marco-disco-and-david-buzatu).

Comment: now I can't extract the values like before anymore. `var last_id = results[0].last_id` doesn't work anymore. how to do it with mysql2?

Comment: You should be able. Print your result and see if its right. Follow this answer for more details on how to make 2 API calls with `node-mysql2' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23267627/11023871)

Comment: now works. I tried with hard coded data (the array) and it does what I need. just `results[0]` doesn't give me nothing back. (undefined) . is a `TextRow` and not a `Raw Packet`

Comment: Try to stringify it with `JSON` and tell me if it helps.
`res=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))`

Comment: I tried stringify alone  and it doesn't work and with parse neither

Comment: Let's continue in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you should make sure that you use `node-mysql2` instead of `node-mysql`. `node-mysql2` has a built in functionality that helps making multiple queries inside a single connection. I have provided you this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184030/connection-query-then-is-not-a-function/52185624#52185624) that exemplifies how to use it properly.

Moving forward, after you've done that, to be able to work with your `result` object, you will need `JSON`.

The following syntax is what you probably want to use:

```
var stringify = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
for (var i = 0; i < stringify.length; i++) {
    var last_id = stringify[i]["last_id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`I need to make 2 requests to my API to insert data in 2 different table:`

From code, I see that you are intending to do a single API call to the server and run 2 queries.

You can do `.then` only on a Promise, so as we can see `connection.query` is not returning a Promise and hence not then able.

Also you are setting response headers multiple times  `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` do this only once in a request cycle. So lets follow the callback approach instead of then.

```
  let sql = "SELECT MAX(id) + 1 AS last_id FROM entries;"; // I get the id
  let query = connection
    .query(sql, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        return res.status(500).send({error:'server error'});
         
     }
        
    // put the id in a variable
    var last_id = results[0].last_id;
    var categoriesMap = req.body.categories;
    var valCat = Object.values(categoriesMap);

    // I create the array with other data
 
    var catArray = valCat.map((item) => {
        return [last_id, item];
      });
    let sql = `BEGIN; INSERT INTO entries (title,kindof) VALUES("${[
        req.body.title,
      ]}","${req.body.kindof}");
     INSERT INTO categories_main (entry_id, cat_id) VALUES  ? ;
     COMMIT;`;

     let query = connection.query(sql, [catArray], (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
           res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
           return res.status(500).send({error:'server error'});
        }
        console.log(results);
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.send("Entry added to DB");
      });
    })
```

Comment: thanks but like this I can't pass the array I created

Comment: I believe you are talking about `catArray` . Why cant you pass it to second connection.query ? Also I think there is not need to pass `[catArray]` that will make it a array of array

Comment: I pass it on the second query cause is where I need it

Comment: Understand that. As you can see the code I am indeed passing that in the second query. I am trying  to understand why you think you cant pass it to second query.

Comment: I don't understand. I need to put that array into the second query, or it can be even a third.

Comment: Dont you see catArray passed as second parameter in `let query = connection.query(sql, [catArray], (err, results) => {`

Answer (score 0):

Here the complete solution, starting from what @SubinSebastian advised to me.

First of all I needed `node-mysql2`, that alows promises and therefore chained requests.

And then:

```
    router.post("/addentry", function (req, res) {
     
     let sql = "SELECT MAX(id) + 1 AS last_id FROM entries;";
    
      connection.promise().query(sql)
        .then((results) => {
        
    
          // I get the value from results
          var stringify = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
          for (var i = 0; i < stringify.length; i++) {
            console.log(stringify[i]["last_id"]);
            var last_id = stringify[i]["last_id"];
          }
    

          // I get some parameters and I create the array
          
          var categoriesMap = req.body.categories;
    
          var valCat = Object.values(categoriesMap);
    
          var catArray = valCat.map((item) => {
            return [last_id, item];
          });
    
    
          let sql = `BEGIN; INSERT INTO entries (title,kindof) VALUES("${[
            req.body.title,
          ]}","${req.body.kindof}");
    
         INSERT INTO categories_main (entry_id, cat_id) VALUES  ? ;
    
         COMMIT;`;

    // array as second query parameter

          let query = connection.query(sql, [catArray], (err,results) => {
            if (err) throw err;     
          });
        })
        .catch(console.log);
```